# hybrid application making a database call using sqlite and angular 2

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am currently developing a mobile app using ionic 2. i have this set of code that need to retrieve data from sqlite and then further take this value for some other functionality. See below

```js
this.credentials = _credentials;
let username = _credentials.username;
let password = _credentials.password;
let cVersion;
**this.localDbService.getcVersion().then((data) => {
    cVersion = data;
});**
console.log(cVersion);
//build http header and make http call to servlet to retrieve details
let myHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
let digest = btoa(`${username}:${password}`);
```

The value of cVersion is null since I am guessing that the call to sqlite is an asynchronous one. One quick fix which I think would work will be to include all the next logic in the database call function getcVersion but is there any solution like waiting for the database call to end and then continue executing after?

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: I think that is the whole purpose of `.then()` function. You can shift all the code you have which needs `cVersion`, in it's `.then()` part. Also, make sure to take necessary actions in `.catch()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Replace this

this.credentials = _credentials; 
let username = _credentials.username; 
let password = _credentials.password; 
let cVersion;

 this.localDbService.getcVersion()
.then((data) => { 

cVersion = data;

console.log(cVersion);

//build http header and make http call to servlet to retrieve details 
let myHeaders: Headers = new Headers(); 
let digest = btoa(`${username}:${password}`);

 });
```

Cheers!